# Changing sql query output depending on a column value

Tags: sql

I have two types of customers in a table, privileged and normal users. When I select some column values from the customers table I want default values for normal users whereas I need actual values for privileged users.
query:

```
select name,id,budget,employees,duration from customers
where reg_date >= to_date( '01-SEP-2012','dd-mmm-yyyy') 
  and reg_date <= to_date('01-OCT-2012','dd-mmm-yyyy')
```

For normal users I need the values of budget, employees, duration columns as 0.

I have to query another table by 'id' and 'reg_mode' to check if a user is privileged user or not. I may be advised that I should have a column in customers table to include 'type' of the customer. Unfortunately I am not authorized to modify the tables. Any ideas to pull the values with lesser latency?

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got it, specially because the tables structure is not so clear...
Lets suppose the other table name is user_type. I suppose what you want is (note my query can have minor errors since I didn't try, I just want to give an idea of the structure):

```
select name,id, '0' as budget, '0' as employees, '0' as duration from customers 
inner join user_type on
       customers.id = user_type.id
where reg_date >= to_date( '01-SEP-2012','dd-mmm-yyyy')  
  and reg_date <= to_date('01-OCT-2012','dd-mmm-yyyy') 
  and user_type.reg_mode = 'normal'

union

select name,id, budget, employees, as duration from customers 
inner join user_type on
       customers.id = user_type.id
where reg_date >= to_date( '01-SEP-2012','dd-mmm-yyyy')  
  and reg_date <= to_date('01-OCT-2012','dd-mmm-yyyy') 
  and user_type.reg_mode = 'privileged'
```

Inner join is similar to where, please let me know if you have questions regarding that terminology...

Comment: You might want to consider writing `union all` in place of `union` to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things here:

1. Join your second table which has information about `reg_mode`:

   SELECT *
   FROM customers JOIN reg_data ON customers.ID = reg_data.ID

   See details on `JOIN` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) for example
2. Select correct values depending on `reg_mode`:

   SELECT (CASE reg_mode WHEN "privileged" THEN customers.budget ELSE 0 END) as budget,
   ...

   See details on `CASE` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181765.aspx) for SQL server. For other databases it should be more or less the same